# Is the number of attacks on civilian freighters in the Black Sea unusual for a war (well, past WWII)?

Tags: armed-conflict, transportation

It seems not a day goes by without a report of an attack on yet another freighter in the Black Sea. Today an Estonian freighter [sank](https://www.maritime-executive.com/article/estonian-cargo-ship-sinks-after-possible-mine-strike-near-odessa). Earlier in the conflict a Moldovan tanker with Russian crew was set ablaze and abandoned. Various other ships (Turkish-, Japanese-owned) have been [hit](https://www.fleetmon.com/maritime-news/2022/37381/japanese-bulk-carrier-hit-missile-count-stricken-s/) by shelling or missiles.

Is this is an unusual number of civil freighters hit, particularly for non-combatant countries?

I'm asking because the US and the UK usually raise concerns about freedom of navigation etc., but I haven't seen much in the way of that kind of protests during this war.

Answer (score 7):

So-called [Tanker War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanker_War) during the larger [Iran-Iraq War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iran%E2%80%93Iraq_War) saw multiple (several hundred, in fact) attacks on civilian shipping, the vast majority of which was not owned by belligerents. It was both to damage the enemy economy and to provoke owners of the ships into putting political pressure on opponents.

That conflict is relevant, because just as the Persian Gulf, the Black Sea is a relatively small body of water with very heavy traffic. Moreover, the city of Odessa is both a trading hub and a military base, and rumours of an incoming Russian naval attack abound in Ukrainian media; one of linked articles mentions suspicions of Russian landing party using the ship (or the ship's tranceiver) as cover.

Why US or UK are not protesting? Well, it took some time for the US to react to attacks during the Tanker War. We might see some diplomatic movement in the future. Up to this point - UK or US ships were not under attack.

Comment: I don't understand how "the Red Sea" is relevant here. Do you mean "The Persian Gulf" ?

Comment: @Evargalo *facepalm* yes, of course.